# Only update a certain number of records

Tags: oracle

Need to update a certain number of rows and the ID can have many results.

```
TABLE1

ID      PHONE        INCLUDE
123456  5071239898  
789012  8765242301  
789012  9855468712  
888777  7635072525  
999999  6121234567  
999999  9526544567
```

What I need to do is select a total of 2 unique records but include all of it's results.

So after the update/select:

```
ID      PHONE        INCLUDE
123456  5071239898   YES    
789012  8765242301   YES    
789012  9855468712   YES    
888777  7635072525   NO
999999  6121234567   NO
999999  9526544567   NO
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post up some of your code and what you've already tried?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Could you add the desired result?

Comment: So there is a 1 to many relationship; actually the max number of records per ID is 2.  I only need to select 2 unique records but need to include all of records associated with the ID.  So if you do SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM TABLE1 WHERE INCLUDE = 'YES" the result is: Count: 3 - Count Distinct 2.

Comment: I was thinking possibly a PARTITION by ROW_NUMBER, RANK or DENSE_RANK but not getting them to work.  Thinking that I possibly need to flatten the records and then update?  Not sure, just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dense_rank()` function to assign a rank number to each row, which will be the same for all rows with the same ID - by partitioning on the ID column.

```
select id, phone, include, dense_rank() over (order by id) as rnk
from table1;

        ID      PHONE INC        RNK
---------- ---------- --- ----------
    123456 5071239898              1
    789012 8765242301              2
    789012 9855468712              2
    888777 7635072525              3
    999999 6121234567              4
    999999 9526544567              4
```

and then use a case expression to convert those rankings into YES/NO:

```
select id, phone,
  case when dense_rank() over (order by id) < 3 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as include
from table1;

        ID      PHONE INC
---------- ---------- ---
    123456 5071239898 YES
    789012 8765242301 YES
    789012 9855468712 YES
    888777 7635072525 NO 
    999999 6121234567 NO 
    999999 9526544567 NO
```

If you want to update the original table - which might not be a good idea as it will go stale; a view that does the calculation might be better - then you could use the same mechanism within a merge:

```
merge into table1 t
using (
  select rowid, dense_rank() over (order by id) as rnk
  from table1
) s
on (s.rowid = t.rowid)
when matched then
update set t.include = case when s.rnk < 3 then 'YES' else 'NO' end;

6 rows merged.

select * from table1;

        ID      PHONE INC
---------- ---------- ---
    123456 5071239898 YES
    789012 8765242301 YES
    789012 9855468712 YES
    888777 7635072525 NO 
    999999 6121234567 NO 
    999999 9526544567 NO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b999b706c583e50d95b2958a920a0ee1)

After comment on question:

```
select count(*), count(distinct id) from TABLE1 where include = 'YES';

  COUNT(*) COUNT(DISTINCTID)
---------- -----------------
         3                 2
```